# How to remove .html extension from URL in SFCC B2C

Tags: commerce-cloud, b2c

I'm trying to accomplish something here with Page Designer but haven't got there yet.
I need to remove the page .html extension from Page Designer's generated url.
Here is an example.

I've got the following url.
https:///s/<site_id>/<page_id>.html

What I'm trying achieve is the following:
https:///s/<site_id>/<page_id>

Is there any way I could remove the extension from a Page Designer's automatically generated url?

Thanks in advance!

See you all!

Answer (score 1):

The “.html” can not be removed. There is also no configuration to disable it.

The only way to do this is custom development, though this adds a layer of complexity.

Here is an example:

https://github.com/taurgis/plugin_dynamicurl

Comment: Thanks Thomas, for your prompt response.
I'll check this plugin out to see if attends my demand. 

Thanks again!